# How do I configure a TimerTrigger in Azure Webjob V3?

Tags: azure-webjobssdk, timer-trigger

I've just updated a webjob to version 3 of the azure-sdk. The job has a TimerTrigger and as an alternative to create an appsettings.json file with the connectionstring I was hoping to use the [TimerOptions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Config/TimersOptions.cs) class to set the ConnectionString but to my surprise the class is empty?!.

I stumbled across this https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2178

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to the above scenario regarding the TimerTrigger. In the ConfigureHostConfiguration we can use the AddInMemoryCollection to set the connectionString "AzureWebJobsStorage".

```
Dictionary<string, string> connectionStrings =
   new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
      { "AzureWebJobsStorage", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsStorage"].ConnectionString},
};

builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
   {
      config.AddInMemoryCollection(connectionStrings);
   });
```

Sadly this will not work on ServiceBusTriggers. But with ServiceBusTriggers we have an ServiceBusOptions that is not empty and can therefore be used.

```
builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
   {
      b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
      b.AddServiceBus(options =>
      {
         options.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = false;
         options.ConnectionString = 
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsServiceBus"].ConnectionString;
      });

      b.AddTimers();
});
```